# ActionScript: How to load a SWF video into a MovieClip and manipulate all the Frames in the video

Tags: video, actionscript, flash, frames, movieclip

```
private function onLoadComplete(event:Event) : void
    {
        movieClip = new MovieClip();
        movieClip.addChild(mcLoader);
        addChild(movieClip);
        trace(movieClip.totalFrames);
    }
```

The mcLoader is used to load a external .swf file which is a video file I converted from .flv. The video plays well but the trace outputs 1, which means there is only 1 frame in the movieClip, that's not what I want. I thought I can manipulate all the frames in video.

Comment: Erm.. You're adding a `new` MovieClip, of course it only has a single frame?

Comment: Try mcLoader.totalFrames instead.

Comment: not enough information. If mcLoader is a Loader instance, you can get to total number of frames in the loaded mc like so: `MovieClip(mcLoader.content).totalFrames` , this of course, assuming you're video is embedded in the main timeline of the loaded swf.